# Not able to display widgets in QGridLayout from MainWindow

Tags: qt, widget, grid-layout

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    reminderTextEdit     = new QTextEdit("");
    reminderTextEdit->setPlaceholderText("What do you want to be reminded of?");
    /// Setting parent is necessary otherwise it will be created in a window of its own.
    reminderTextEdit->setParent(this);
    reminderTextEdit->show();

    dateComboBox         = new QComboBox();
    dateComboBox->setParent(this);
    dateComboBox->show();

    monthComboBox        = new QComboBox();
    monthComboBox->setParent(this);
    monthComboBox->show();

    yearComboBox         = new QComboBox();
    yearComboBox->setParent(this);
    yearComboBox->show();

    doneAndAddMoreButton = new QPushButton();
    doneAndAddMoreButton->setParent(this);
    doneAndAddMoreButton->show();

    doneAndQuitButton    = new QPushButton();
    doneAndQuitButton->setParent(this);
    doneAndQuitButton->show();

    gridLayout           = new QGridLayout;
    gridLayout->addWidget(reminderTextEdit, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    gridLayout->addWidget(dateComboBox, 1, 0);
    gridLayout->addWidget(monthComboBox, 1, 1);
    gridLayout->addWidget(yearComboBox, 1, 2);
    gridLayout->addWidget(doneAndAddMoreButton, 2, 0);
    gridLayout->addWidget(doneAndQuitButton, 2, 1);
}
```

This code just produces a parent window and a child window in it.

Adding `setLayout(gridLayout);` at the end of it produces following error:

`QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on MainWindow "", which already has a layout`

Point out the wrong doings, please.

Comment: have you already defined a layout for the main window in the qt designer?

Comment: (also just an advice on the side. Most of the constructors of the Qt objects take a parent pointer. So you can use something like `new QPushButton(this);` and don't need to call the setParent method afterwards.

Comment: @Hayt I have _not_ done anything in qt designer. Haven't even opened it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QMainWindow has already a fixed layout. So you cannot reassign one. See here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#details

> QMainWindow has its own layout to which you can add QToolBars,
>   QDockWidgets, a QMenuBar, and a QStatusBar. The layout has a center
>   area that can be occupied by any kind of widget.

What you can do is set an "empty" widget as central widget and give it the layout.

```
QWidget *centralWidget = new QWidget(); //set parent to this
//...
reminderTextEdit = new QTextEdit("");
reminderTextEdit->setPlaceholderText("What do you want to be reminded of?");
//...

centralWidget->setLayout(gridLayout);    
setCentralWidget(window);
```

**EDIT:**

As @thuga mentioned in the comments: when you add a widget to the layout it will take the responsibility of the item (reparent them). So when you add the items to the layout you **don't** need to declare a parent in the first place.

The same goes for the widget you provide to `setCentralWidget`

Comment: When you add widgets to layouts they get reparented. You don't have to set the parent for those widgets. Same goes when you set the central widget.

Comment: @thuga oh nice I did not know that. I will add that

Comment: It's not mentioned in the `QLayout::addWidget` method's documentation, so it's not immediately obvious, but you can find it mentioned in the [layout management documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html#tips-for-using-layouts).

Comment: @thuga it is mentioned in `addItem` though. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#addItem

Comment: Well not really. `QLayoutItem` is not the widget itself, nor is it responsible for destroying the widget.