# qt creator how to get layout from main window?

Tags: c++, qt, c++14

I am trying to dynamically add QTableViews to a mainwindow when a button is pressed.

It looks like the widget class has a member layout and I can set it.

**qwidget.h:**

```
public:
    QLayout *layout() const;
    void setLayout(QLayout *);
```

**main:**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout();
    MainWindow w;
    w.setLayout( layout );
    w.show();


    return a.exec();
}
```

**part of mainwindow.cpp:**

```
void MainWindow::on_btn_main_run_clicked()
{

    this->Run();

}

void MainWindow::Run() {

    this->up_dr_ = std::make_unique<DataReader>(
        DataReader( "C:/CPP/Simulator/log_file.txt" )
    );
    up_dr_->ReadFile();
    up_dr_->PrintLines();

    TableModel model( this );
    QTableView table_view;
    table_view.setModel( &model );

    // this line below there does not work. It throws the error left of add widget must point to class/...
    this->layout->addWidget( &table_view );

    table_view.show();

}
```

I can't get the layout member from the mainwindow to attach the qtableview, so when I run it the view just briefly pops up as its own window.

I am new to c++ and qt, so there may be something I am doing fundamentally wrong. Is this the right way to get the layout and attach it and if so what is my mistake here? If not, how should I tackle this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to display widgets in QGridLayout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39956017/not-able-to-display-widgets-in-qgridlayout)

Comment: Btw: you should add a compiler error to your question. You should change it go `this->layout()->addWidget(...)`. Note the **()** . But it maybe will still not work as you think it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [CentralWiget function](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html#centralWidget). First of all, create a widget and set it as your central widget. Now, define a layout for your central widget, per example: Horizontal layout:

```
// Add a layour to your central widget
QHBoxLayout* layout = new QHBoxLayout;
this->centralWidget()->setLayout(layout);
```

When you want to hide/add a widget to the central widget just use:

```
// Now, we could add an element to the widget
QHBoxLayout* layout = this->centralWidget()->layout();
QTableView* view = new QTableView;
view->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding,);
layout->addWidget(view);
```

EXAMPLE:

```
 QWidget* main = new QWidget(this);
main->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
this->setCentralWidget(main);

QHBoxLayout* layout = new QHBoxLayout(this);
this->centralWidget()->setLayout(layout);

QTableWidget* table = new QTableWidget(this);
table->setColumnCount(2);
table->setRowCount(3);
table->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
this->centralWidget()->layout()->addWidget(table);
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: care to add some explanation?

Comment: I added this to my main
w.centralWidget()->setLayout( layout );
and this to the Run() method
this->centralWidget()->layout()->addWidget( &table_view );

so now it builds but the table_view does not show up at all

Comment: use QSizePolicy to expand the size of the widget. See my last changes

Comment: I have added a complete example